# Propel ORM - Iterating over data from find() does NOT hint to getters

Tags: phpstorm, propel, getter

It's one of those things that annoys me.

I retrieve data using `find()` method, and iterate using foreach :

```
$ladies = ValentineQuery::create()->find();

foreach ($ladies as $maybe) 
{
    echo $maybe->getSeconddate();  //<-- DOES NOT AUTO HINT AT GETTER METHODS!!! arg
}
```

`getSeconddate()` actually works fine but does not auto hint at available getters.

If I use`findPk()` method, my IDE will auto hint at the getters.

Anyone having same issues? I hope it's just my editor.

**Propel 1.7, PhpStorm 4.0.3, PHP 5.3 on WIN7**

Comment: So .. what do you want to be done: make it work automatically? If so -- maybe try latest **v7.1.2** as 4.0.3 is quite old and there were improvements in this area (hell .. they will publish v8 EAP in 2-3 weeks). If you are happy with a bit of type hinting (and this should work for sure) -- just use PHPDoc comment: `/** @var MyClass[] $ladies */` before $ladies assignment .. or `/** @var MyClass $maybe */ before/inside foreach statement.

Comment: Tried v7.1.2 and didnt hint.  PHPDoc comment made me happy.  Thanks for addressing the newb on this.  I guess i'll move on and stop wasting time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of these PHPDoc comments will do the job for you (if you do not mind little bit of manual type hinting, of course):

```
/** @var MyClass[] $ladies */
$ladies = ValentineQuery::create()->find();

/** @var MyClass $maybe */
foreach ($ladies as $maybe) 
{
    /** @var MyClass $maybe */
    echo $maybe->getSeconddate();  //<-- DOES NOT AUTO HINT AT GETTER METHODS!!! arg
}
```

For more automated stuff (so that you do not have to place such type hints everywhere), check PHPDocs for those methods -- maybe it will be possible to place them there (e.g. `@return MyClass[]`) .. or via `@method` tag in the class PHPDoc (it all depends on how it's implemented -- cannot say for sure as I'm not good with Propel at all).